# WebBrowser control Automation Server Can't Create ShockwaveFlash ActiveXObject

Tags: javascript, flash, internet-explorer, activex, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to load an external webpage in the winforms WebBrowser control. I have IE (9.0.8112.16421) + .NET 4.0 installed on the machine. The page contains a script element with the src attribute set to a .js file containing a function that runs Flash detection. The IE specific section of that function contains the following snippet...

[image: IE Flash Detection via ActiveX Automation Server Failure]

As you can see it fails with the above, 'Automation server can't create object', exception. It fails in the WebBrowser control and it fails in IE if I manually load the page (same exception).

The non-IE section of the same script detects my Flash installation correctly via navigator.plugins when I manually load the page in FF/Chrome indicating Flash is installed correctly on the machine. For IE I've tried running the page/script with all ActiveX settings enabled, Scripting settings enabled, Protected Mode disabled, and with the host that serves the page and the host that serves the script both added to Trusted Sites. For the WebBrowser control I've also tried attaching a custom security manager where ProcessUrlAction allows everything. Despite this I hit the same exception every time.

I'm hoping someone could suggest why this is happening and let me know what else I can try to get it to work inside the WebBrowser control?

Thanks.